# Can't find backup files on Macintosh HD?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, filesystem

When opening the OS X System information it says I have 67 GB backups:

[image: "Säkerhetskopior" = "Backups"]

But when I'm using Disk Inventory X to find large files on my Mac i can't find any backups files:

[image: Disk Inventory X]

I don't know anything about any backups files stored locally. I have a backup to a Time Capsule.

Disk Inventory X says I only using 69 GB, but the System information says I have 140 GB.

Can I delete the backup files and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backups are stored in a hidden volume called `.MobileBackups`. These are Time Machine's local snapshots. They are separate backups that save previous versions of files for cases where your Time Machine drive is not available. You shouldn't modify the contents of this volume directly, and therefore it is usually not visible in most cases.

You can disable local snapshots by running `sudo tmutil disablelocal`.

<sup>Re-enable with `sudo tmutil enablelocal`.</sup>